# Is generating your own JWT Bearer the same as OAuth/OpenID Connect?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt, openid-connect

Since I don't know, and can't find information about this:

When I have an ASP.NET Core WebAPI with a AuthenticationController.cs where I have a Login()-method that generates a JWT Bearer token with JwtSecurityToken class, is that considered an OAuth2.0 and/or OpenID Connect (or neither)? And is my approach safe (enough) to protect my API?

I'm trying to understand OAuth2.0 and OpenID Connect, and if I'm using it already or not.

And if I should switch my way of security to something like IdentityServer for the use of OAuth2.0 & OpenID Connect.

Answer (score 1):

JwtBearer token is just part of OAuth2.0 https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/ but OAuth2.0 as topic itself is much bigger then just jwt token

> And if I should switch my way of security to something like IdentityServer for the use of OAuth2.0 & OpenID Connect.

It depends on the requirement that if you want to maintain user information within your application or you want to delegate that task to another application like identityserver